# Como obtener el valor de numeric en un valor datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola necesito hacer esto :
Basado en la tabla de histórico de sueldos el SP debe contener 4 columnas correspondientes 
al sueldo básico de los últimos 4 meses, para los casos que no aplique 
según su fecha de ingreso la columna contendrá 0.00 (no dejar en null)

```
declare @idperi int,@fch_inicio int,@fch_fin int
set @idperi=7
set @fch_inicio=(select month(FechaInicio) from Periodo where PeriodoID=@idperi)
--set @fch_fin=(select month(FechaFin) from Periodo where PeriodoID=@idperi)

print @fch_inicio

select k.FechaIngreso,k.NombrePersonal,k.ApellidoPaterno,h.sueldo ,
case  
when MONTH(k.FechaIngreso)<@fch_inicio then h.sueldo
 else 0 end AS Enero
 from Personal k
inner join SueldoHistorico h on k.PersonalID=h.personal_id
```

tengo una tabla periodo y tabla personal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado tambien mi tabla sueldo historico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado de mi consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Cuál es el problema con el código que tienes en tu pregunta?

Comment: El problema es que si te fijas bien el primer trabajador empezó a trabajar en julio por lo tanto no deberia tener valor en los campos enero,febrero , etc